# Add extra attributes to link in wordpress gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I would like to add a couple of custom attributes to the link popup on the Gutenberg editor in wordpress. Would like to have something in the following lines:
[image]

There is currently a pending issue for the same on the Gutenberg's Github page: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/11599

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: @Joundill I am not looking for help with the exact code, but was looking for an answer on feasibility. Even if it is possible with the help of a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/extend-link/ which only works for classic editor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking to extend with new controls the link panel. However, I did not found an easy to understand exemple yet. Here is how the [Yoast Seo plugin](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/14.4.1/js/src/inline-links/edit-link.js) is doing though.